# How do I execute a query with PHP without having the trouble I have?

Tags: php, sql, date, time, range

Hey guys i have two date inputs containing three dropboxes for day,month and year each.
day has a name d1, month=m2,year=y1 and similarly for the second date input its d2,m2 and y2

i'm trying to query the database for information between a particular date range.

```
  $date1=date("Y-m-d", mktime(0, 0, 0, $_POST['m1'], $_POST['d1'],$_POST['y1']));
  $date2=date("Y-m-d", mktime(0, 0, 0, $_POST['m2'], $_POST['d2'],$_POST['y2']));

  echo $date1." and ".$date2;

$query="SELECT *FROM FDB where time BETWEEN ".$date1." and ".$date2;
$f = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$nfiles= mysql_num_rows($f);

$query="SELECT *FROM usr where created BETWEEN ".$date1." and ".$date2;
$f = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$nus= mysql_num_rows($f);
```

It is showing an error on the line below

```
$query="SELECT *FROM history WHERE ACTIVITY='Logged In' where CAST(FLOOR(CAST(time AS FLOAT))AS DATETIME) between ".$date1." AND ".$date2;
```

The error is

```
          You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to  your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where CAST(FLOOR(CAST(time AS FLOAT))AS DATETIME) between `2011-01-01` AND `2012' at line 1
```

How do I need to change my code so that I don't get the error any longer?

Comment: You  got two WHERE clause in your SQLstatement.

Comment: Just sleepy to apply the correct syntax of SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got 2 WHERE clauses on your code.

Try this way

```
$query="SELECT * FROM history 
        WHERE ACTIVITY='Logged In' 
            AND CAST(FLOOR(CAST(time AS FLOAT))AS DATETIME) 
            between ".$date1." AND ".$date2;
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two `WHERE`s in your query. Replace the second one with `AND`.

Most "you have an error in your query" messages point to exact character where MySQL got confused, so you should look for an error *before* that.